# AttributeError: object has no attribute 'box'

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

What's wrong with my app??

```
import sys
import time
import random
from tkinter import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class WindowHello(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    frame = QFrame()
    palette = QPalette()
    layout = QHBoxLayout()

    palette.setBrush(QPalette.Background,QBrush(QPixmap("First hello.gif")))
    frame.setFixedSize(450, 380)
    frame.setLayout(layout)
    frame.setPalette(palette)
    frame.show()

    self.setGeometry(650, 450, 450, 380)
    self.box.addWidget(frame.setBrush)
    self.box.addWidget(frame.setFixedSize)
    self.box.addWidget(frame.setLayout)
    self.box.addWidget(frame.setPalette)
    self.box = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.setLayout(self.box)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

op = WindowHello()
op.setWindowTitle('LangTIME')
op.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('Minilogowin.png'))
op.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When i try run this code it's showing me error:

```
AttributeError: 'WindowHello' object has no attribute 'box'
```

Please help me solve this problem. 
I'm sorry if this question stupid, i'm still new.

Comment: Is your indentation correct?  It looks like most of what I expect is supposed to be the body of `__init__` is indented too far out and would be part of the class definition instead

Comment: I had to fix indentation but after that got the error you describe. Below the line where you `setGeometry()` there are a handful of lines that refer to `self.box`. You haven't defined that yet.

Comment: Why are you importing tkinter and PyQt4? You can't use those two together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set a variable **before** using it.
2. Add the widget (`frame`) instead of its methods (`frame.setFixedSize` etc.) into the box using `addWidget`.

Correct way to do it:

```
self.box = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()   # Set self.box before using it.
self.box.addWidget(frame)
```